# Error importing package in NiFi ExecuteScript

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I am trying to use ExecuteScript to execute a python script. I logged in as root and installed all the necessary python packages for one my python packages in the HDF sandbox. I am able to import this package from a python prompt. But when I try to import it from within ExecuteScript I get import error  for my package which was installed. Why does NiFi not find the package?

Comment: where did you install these packages ? did you have restarted Nifi ?

Comment: NiFi uses Jython which requires pure Python (not native CPython) modules, which package(s) are you trying to import that give you an error?

Comment: @mattyb - I am using my Python package 'yorkpy'. This needs other packages like pyyaml,pandas, matplotlib etc. These are regular python packages. I was able to start a Python command prompt and import the package

Comment: Pandas and matplot lib are CPython modules, not pure Python modules IIRC. A "Pure Python" module is one that is written strictly in Python and doesn't itself depend on any other native (CPython) modules. Since ExecuteScript is not Python but Jython, it has the limitation of only being able to import pure Python modules. If you need full Python capability you can try `ExecuteStreamCommand` instead of `ExecuteScript`.